# args[max_input] woocommerce if statement confused

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Cant seem to figure this out with if statements. Wanting it to show QTY 4 unless stock available is less than 4..

So far I have this..

```
function wpse_292293_quantity_input_default( $args, $product ) {
    $args['max_value'] = $product->managing_stock() ? $product->get_stock_quantity() : 100;
    $args['input_value'] = 4;
    

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'wpse_292293_quantity_input_default', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: So - `$args['input_value'] = min(4, $product->get_stock_quantity());` ...?

Comment: Exactly the combo I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: Is this only applicable if `$product->managing_stock()` returns `true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wanting it to show QTY 4 unless stock available is less than 4..

So that would be the minimum of the actual available stock, and 4.

```
$args['input_value'] = min(4, $product->get_stock_quantity());
```